# How to match `<<` only at the beginning of every line?

Tags: vim

I want to search `<<` at the beginning of the lines in the following text.

```
<<test
test<<
test<<test
<<test
```

The result I expect are `<<` in the first line and the 4th line , not include 3rd line .
I tried to use `\<<<` to match prefix . But it is useless . What should I do ?
Thank you .

Comment: It’s not clear which of these should match. Do you mean “line”, or “word”, or…?

Comment: `<<test` is enough. There is nothing to escape, here.

Comment: Maybe you want something like `/[^<]\?\zs<<`?  It's not really clear why `/<<test` does not do what you want.

Comment: Do you want to consider the 3rd line a match?  It's still not clear if you want to include that or not.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Sorry for my  bad expression . Like the code example  , I want to search `<<te` in  the first line and 4th line but not inlucde 3rd line .

Comment: That edit clarifies!  If you just want to match beginning of line, use `/^<<`

Comment: @Ry-  I edited the problem again and got solution . Thank you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match the beginning of a line, use the atom `^`.  This should do what you want:

```
/^<<
```

Comment: Thank you . I don't know vim can use regex to find before .

Comment: Classic regex expressions and vim go hand in hand.  Note that `^` and `$` are movement commands that move to beginning of line and end of line, respectively, matching the anchoring behavior of those characters in an RE.  `vi` is extremely intuitive that way, and you will see a lot of similar behavior throughout.